# Make bootstrap 5.0 carousel dynamic using ACF and CPT UI

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make bootstrap 5.0 carousel (with indicators) dynamic using ACF and CPT UI. I realized that I need to display the number in `data-bs-slide-to` dynamically, as well as other numbers and arrows and the `class="active"` also dynamically, but I don't know how. I now have all the slides displayed at once - one on top of the other. If you insert the parameter `'posts_per_page' => 1`, then the first slide is visible, as it should be, but the carousel does not spin.

**My code:**

```
<!-- Carousel from bootstrap-->
<div id="carouselBootStrap" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
   <li data-bs-target="#carouselBootStrap" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1">1</li>
   <li data-bs-target="#carouselBootStrap" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2">2</li>
   <li data-bs-target="#carouselBootStrap" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3">3</li>
 </ol>
 <div class="carousel-inner"> 


<?php $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'slider_feature', 'orderby' => 'ID', 'order' => 'ASC' )); ?>

<?php  while ($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post(); ?>

 <div class="carousel-item active dark-header-overlay">
     <h2 class="centered font-sl-head"><?php the_field('slide_text'); ?> <img class="img-hline" src="<?php the_field('small_slide_img'); ?>" alt=""></h2>
     
     <img class="d-block w-100 h-70" src="<?php the_field('img_slide'); ?>" alt="">
      
   </div>

<?php endwhile; 
wp_reset_query(); ?>


 </div>

 <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselBootStrap" data-bs-slide="prev">
   <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
 </button>
 <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselBootStrap" data-bs-slide="next">
   <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
 </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found a solution:**

Make loop everywhere and increment `i` variable

```
<!-- Carousel from bootstrap-->
<div id="carouselBootStrap" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
<?php $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'slider_feature', 'orderby' => 'ID', 'order' => 'ASC' )); ?>

  <?php if( $loop->have_posts()): $i = 0; ?>
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <?php while ($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <li data-bs-target="#carouselBootStrap" data-bs-slide-to="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="<?php if($i == 0) echo 'active'; ?>" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1">
      <!-- here I have number links -->
      <?php echo $i+1; ?></li>
      <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>  
  </ol>
<?php endif; ?>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
<?php if( $loop->have_posts()): $i = 0; ?>
<?php  while ($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post(); ?>

  <div class="carousel-item dark-header-overlay <?php if($i == 0) echo 'active'; ?>">
      <h2 class="centered font-sl-head"><?php the_field('slide_text'); ?> <img class="img-hline" src="<?php the_field('small_slide_img'); ?>" alt=""></h2>
      
      <img class="d-block w-100 h-70" src="<?php the_field('img_slide'); ?>" alt="">
       
    </div>

<?php $i++; endwhile;  ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

  </div>

  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselBootStrap" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselBootStrap" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
```